# How to filter with a lead lag window on a spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, filter, window, apache-spark-sql

The `filter` function select all the rows in a Spark dataframe which satisfy certain conditions. How would I do *window-filter* where a set of rows above and below the row, which satisfies the filter condition, are selected? For example, I have the following dataframe `myDF`:

```
A    B
1    1
2    12
3    13
4    14
5    10
6    17
7    34
8    12
9    1
10    7
11    1
```

Now I want to write something like `myDF.orderBy($"A").myWindowFilter("B" === 12, 2)` which will give me the following dataframe (2 is the lag/lead width):

```
A    B
1    1
2    12
3    13
4    14
6    17
7    34
8    12
9    1
10    7
```

How do I implement such a function `myWindowFilter` in Scala/Spark?